# PHP/SQL Query: combine two tables with only unique records and count saturdays

Tags: mysql, sql, date, unique

I have two MySQL tables, called "accounts" and "events".

**Accounts**

| ID | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Pete |
| 2 | Josh |
| 3 | Harry |

**Events**

| ID | date | account_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-11 | 1 |
| 2 | 2021-10-23 | 1 |
| 3 | 2021-10-23 | 2 |
| 4 | 2021-11-06 | 1 |

The account_id in the events table is linked to the id in the accounts table.

My question is: which query can I use to count only saturdays (date YYYY-mm-dd format) for each unique user in the accounts table? So I get the next result:

| Name | Saturdays |
| --- | --- |
| Josh | 1 |
| Pete | 2 |
| Harry | 0 |

I've tried many queries (with i.e. the (inner) JOIN, DISTINCT and GROUP BY keywords) but I don't get the exact result. Can you please help me?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Where did you find Harry?!?

Comment: Somewhere in the bushes

Answer (score 0):

I think something like this should work (untested):

```sql
SELECT 
    `a`.`name` AS `Name`,
    COUNT(`e`.`ID`) AS `Saturdays`
FROM `accounts` AS `a`
LEFT JOIN `events` AS `e` ON `e`.`account_id` = `a`.`ID` AND WEEKDAY(`e`.`date`) = 5
GROUP BY `a`.`ID`
```